# Smooth motion for JPanel and update JLabel at same time

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation

How to move with smooth motion for `JPanel` and update `JLabel` at same time?

I want to show current time on a `JFrame` so I created a new `java.util.Timer` and update to label every one second.

I created another Java thread to as well, move the panel component.

But while moving the panel and showing (updating) time on the frame, panel refreshing to form original position.

So I search that problem in Google and can't find the solution.

```
//Code to move jPanel smoothly
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            int i = 0 ;
            public void run(){
                while(i<150){
                    i++;
                    jPanel2.setLocation(i, jPanel2.getY());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

// Code to show Time
       Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                jLabel1.setText(new Date()+"");
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Comment: 1) Never update Swing components from another Thread. Use always `javax.swing.Timer`
2) 1 for timer means 1 millisecond not 1 second.
3) Please provide a small runnable class ([mcve]) so we can reproduce your problems.

Comment: So i need to change **Thread** instead of **javax.swing.timer** for moving jPanel smoothly?

Comment: You need 2 `javax.swing.Timer` objects. One to update clock-label, and another for the movement. And in the second timer you also need to repaint the parent of the moved component.

Comment: but it still not working perfectly. :(

Comment: It is required to [edit] your question rather than [start a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55568558/418556)! Please read the page linked by @SergiyMedvynskyy because the uncompilable code snippet above is **not an** MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example, how to provide animation and update for a component.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <code>MovedClock</code>.
 */
public class MovedClock {

    private final JLabel clock = new JLabel();
    private final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    private void startUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moved clock");
        frame.setLayout(null); // usually it's a bad idea, but for animation we need this.
        clock.setBounds(0, 50, 50, 20);
        frame.add(clock);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        updateClock();
        Timer clockTimer = new Timer(1000, e -> updateClock());
        clockTimer.start();
        // 15 milliseconds for about 60fps
        Timer moveTimer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {

            private int count = 1;

            private int increment = 1;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (count == 435 || count == 0) {
                    increment = -increment;
                }
                Point loc = clock.getLocation();
                loc.x += increment;
                clock.setLocation(loc);
                count += increment;
            }
        });
        moveTimer.start();
    }

    private void updateClock() {
        clock.setText(LocalTime.now().format(format));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MovedClock()::startUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to stop **actionPerform event** after jLabel reached to end of JFrame

Comment: @JianShangQuan Replace the line `increment = -increment;` with the statement `((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();`. In this case the movement will be stopped when label is at the end of the line.